# Encrypted /boot without UEFI

Tags: boot, security, lvm, grub, luks

I have only one, LUKS-encrypted, partition. Is it possible to boot system from /boot on this partition? I don't want to use UEFI to do this.

EDIT

I'm using GRUB.

I have uncommented `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` in `/etc/default/grub`.

I added `cryptdevice=/dev/sda1:b00t` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

I have `HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block encrypt lvm2 filesystems keyboard fsck)` in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`.

Comment: Are you using grub as a bootloader? It should be able to handle /boot being part of a LUKS partition provided you have the needed modules available. Are you asking because you want to set it up this way, or because it is set up like this and you are trying to recover?

Comment: I edited post..